# xgboost Scala API what is `predictContrib`?

Tags: scala, machine-learning, xgboost

I am using `xgboost` with the scala API.

I used to use `xgboost` with `R` and `python` API and I discover recently the `pred_contribs` argument.

For example, in python API, documentation says:

> When this is True the output will be a matrix of size (nsample, nfeats + 1) with each record indicating the feature contributions (SHAP values) for that prediction. The sum of all feature contributions is equal to the raw untransformed margin value of the prediction. Note the final column is the bias term.

As far as I understand, it's a kind of [Tree SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) implementation directly in xgboost.

My question is:

`predictContrib` is the same thing in Scala API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly the same as both end up executing the same code.

Python: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/core.py#L1239

Scala:

1. Starts with [JBooster](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/jvm-packages/xgboost4j/src/main/scala/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/scala/Booster.scala#L155)
2. That one calls [XGBoostJNI.XGBoosterPredict](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/jvm-packages/xgboost4j/src/main/java/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/java/Booster.java#L252)

At the end both call the same [C API](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/src/c_api/c_api.cc#L954)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not sure to understand where the `contribution` part is computed.

Comment: @Thomas Check the link to the C API and follow the code. Essentially, it's a call to `Predict` with a right mask. That being said, your question was if it's the same thing in Python and Scala and my answer proves that it is indeed the case - they arrive at exactly the same code with the same parameters. Do shout though if you believe it's not the case.